# Making Python display .txt files from directories

Tags: python

```
print "Which category would you like to view? Savory, Dessert, Cake, Soup or Drink?    "
category = raw_input()
if category == "Savory": #opens directory according to their answer.
    os.listdir("savory")

elif category == "Drink":
    os.listdir("drink")

elif category == "Cake":
    os.listdir("cake")

elif category == "Dessert":
    os.listdir("dessert")

elif category == "savory":
    os.listdir("savory")

elif category == "drink":
    os.listdir("drink")

elif category == "cake":
    os.listdir("cake")

elif category == "dessert":
    os.listdir("dessert")
```

I am trying to create a code that would display recipes that have been saved under certain directories. when I run the code nothing is displayed even if I input recipes into the directories.

Comment: `print(os.listdir(raw_input().lower()))` - that's it

Comment: @frostnational I may be asking too much here, but does anyone know how to get this code to be displayed as a list rather than like this:['p.txt', 'example.txt'] if not thats fine.

Comment: `['p.txt', 'example.txt']` is actually a list :) If you want to have these filenames on the separate lines, do this: `for x in os.listdir(category): print x`

Comment: @frostnational I tried this with no result. Any ideas why.

Comment: Actually, no ideas. What do you mean by *no result*?

Comment: @frostnational it does not list the text on separate lines and rather it lists them the same as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly,** you're not printing anything. E.g

```
os.listdir("savory")
```

should be

```
print(os.listdir("savory"))
```

**Secondly,** you can dramatically shorten your code:

```
print("Which category would you like to view? Savory, Dessert, Cake, Soup or Drink?")
print(os.listdir(raw_input().lower()))
```

If you want to restrict user from accessing other directories:

```
safe = ['savory', 'dessert', 'cake', 'soup', 'drink']

category = raw_input().lower()
if category in safe:
    print(os.listdir(category))
else:
    print('You have typed an invalid category')
```

Comment: Perhaps wrap it in a `try` block in case the user enters an invalid directory name?